# Trouble inserting media type fields using Python-Eve

Tags: python, eve

I am trying to store an image as part of a document, using the `media` type, but it is crashing with a `bson.errors.InvalidDocument` exception (`InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: <FileStorage: u'test_image.png' ('image/png')>`

My schema is set up as follows:

```
schema = {
    'img': {
        'type':'media'
     }
}
```

I have been using Postman to send a form-data request with the 'img' field set to the image file but `curl -F "img=@test_image.png" http://127.0.0.1:5000/testcol` gets the same result.

It seems that [the part which should store the media](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/blob/f075180f2b78c5804838022d3f2405ca731535c5/eve/methods/common.py#L926) is not being called, as I have tried subclassing the `GridFSMediaStorage` class and overriding the `put` method to add a print statement but nothing is printed. Does anyone know what might be wrong?